# R programming + Data Processing

Tags: r

Consider the “College” dataset in the package “ISLR”.

a) Use the function `summary()` to produce a numerical summary of the variables
in the dataset.
b) Use `pairs()` to produce a scatterplot of the continuous variables in the data set.
c) Create a new qualitative variable called “Elite”, by “binning” the variable “Top10perc”. We are going to divide universities into two groups based on whether or not the proportion of students coming from the two 10% of their high school exceeds 50%. Add this variable to your dataset.
d) Use the table function to figure out how many Elite schools there are.
e) Use the table function to figure out how many of the Elite schools are private.
f) Do elite schools tend to have higher graduation rates?

**NEED HELP WITH (e) and (f)**

*This is what I wrote so far :-*

```r
#install.packages("ISLR")
library(ISLR)
setwd("~/Desktop/spring 2021/STA/Homework/HW1")
data("College")
head(College)
summary(College)
pairs(College[ ,2:18])
College$Elite <- College$Top10perc > 50
summary(College)
table(College$Elite)
```

Summary of the dataset:
[image: summary of the dataset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e) `table(College[College$Private=="Yes",]$Elite)` answers the questions, since `TRUE` frequency is `65`:

However, I prefer to see with "Elite" vs. "Non-Elite":

```
(¬_¬)table(College[College$Private=="Yes",]$Elite)

    Elite Non-Elite 
       65       500
```

f) You can do a one-sided Welch `t.test()` to compare the `Grad.Rate` means between elite vs. non-elite schools:

```
(¬_¬)t.test(Grad.Rate~Elite, College, alternative = "greater")

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  Grad.Rate by Elite
t = 12.986, df = 109.94, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 17.37645      Inf
sample estimates:
    mean in group Elite mean in group Non-Elite 
               83.38462                63.46352
```

Comment: I think the answer to the question "how many of the Elite schools are private" should include both variables `Elite` and `Private`, don't you think? ;-)

Comment: how to see elite and non elite? as for now i see true and false for the code mentioned above